# Force spellcheck on a text field even if the browser setting is turned off

Tags: javascript, html

We can use the html attribute spellcheck="true" but this doesn't work if the browser setting is turned off.

Is it possible to force spellcheck on a text field using html or javascript even if the user has disabled spellcheck on his/her browser?

Comment: No, it’s not possible.

Comment: You shouldn't overrule user settings in the browser in the first place, though.

Comment: There is nothing that stop's you from passing the value of your input through some sort of spell check library or API. You would then have to figure out a method for styling errors inside the input.It's possible but can become overly complex for edge cases that the user has already decided against, so it might not be worth it.